# Can an object change other object's private data?

Tags: c++

If class C can hold another C object, can that child change its parent's private data members?

The code below works but I'm not sure if what I'm doing could be dangerous. (i.e undefined behavior)

```
class C {
public:
    C(C *parent, int num) : _parent(parent), _i(num), _child(nullptr) {}
    ~C() {
        if(_child) {
            delete _child;
            _child = nullptr;
        }
    }

    int get() const { return _i; }

    void addChild() {
        if(!_child) _child = new C(this, 0);
    }

    C* getChild() {
        return _child;
    }

    void setParent(int num) {
        _parent->_i = num; //accessing parent private data
    }

private:
    int _i;
    C *_parent;
    C *_child;
};

int main()
{
    C c(nullptr, 1);
    c.addChild();
    c.getChild()->setParent(25);

    std::cout << c.get() << "\n"; //output is 25 as expected

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it can. `private` members are accessible to instances of same class. Instance can access another instance data.

For example, this is how move constructors/assigment operators work: steal data and delete it from original object to avoid double references to same data.

Comment: Why delete the original object? When doing `C a = b;`, `a` shouldn't be deleted, no?

Comment: @Pipel : delete _data_ from original object, I was talking about how move constructor are usually implemented, not about your code. In your example there are many questions: what it means to assign one object to other. Should they share their childs/parents or new copies should be created? What should happen if you will try to assign child to parent? They probably shouold not be assignable (maybe move assignable).